# Regex for checking file extensions and untitled

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following regex: `(?s)(?i)\.(pdf|doc|docx|xls)|untitled` that checks for filetype extensions or the word untitled.

```
@Transient
    private static final Pattern titlePattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?i)\\.(pdf|doc|docx|xls)$|untitled");
```

Now, my tests are failing because of text such as `.document` or `.docblah`.

How could I modify the regex to stop the regex matching characters after filetype extensions?

Comment: I've got this regex ((\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp)|untitled)$) but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `$` i.e `(?s)(?i)\.(pdf|doc|docx|xls)|untitled`

Comment: that matches .document which is not what i want.

Comment: @unleashed you said  `my tests are failing because of text such as .document or .docblah`...so i guess your regex did what you wanted it to do